# tools used in web development

Tags: web

Is there any website or resource using which we can find out what tools or languages might have been used in developing a particular website..

thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check out the wappalyzer addon of firefox.](http://wappalyzer.com/)

> Wappalyzer is an add-on for Firefox
>   that uncovers the technologies used on
>   websites. It detects CMS and
>   e-commerce systems, message boards,
>   JavaScript frameworks, hosting panels,
>   analytics tools and more.

[image]

Comment: @muqtar: What do you mean by use, it simply shows the techs used by the site you are visiting. It has nothing more to do. It *tells* you and that's its use :)

Comment: ok.. its like just showing THE CMS most of the time.. the tool should atleast show the jsp's js.. AS or flex etc and show some code snippets.. i use fire bug .. but was looking for something more organized..

Comment: I was actually looking for [builtwith](http://builtwith.com). Anyways I will accept your answer as it was close enough.